# Navigation Link'ed view not Full Screen using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

----EDIT 4----

After logging a code support request with Apple they confirmed this is a known bug and to log it as a bug report.

---Original---

I am trying to setup a Navigation Link in my app but whenever I tap the button to transition to the 2nd view the bottom of the screen is taken up by a grey area. Even if I fill screen 2 up with content the grey area still persists. This is a current UIKit app that I am trying to implement SwiftUI with.

I am using a Tab view controller > Hosting view controller. The hosting controller has CoreData context code in because this will/does do stuff with CoreData. These screens have been severely stripped back while I try to figure out what the hell is causing this.

Screen 2 shows after the Tap to Edit button is tapped. The 2 screen show fine in the canvas preview.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

[image: Screen 1 and 2]

Hosting VC Code

```
class TodayHVC: UIHostingController<MyCoreDataViewEnvironmentWrapper> {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        
        let contentView = MyCoreDataViewEnvironmentWrapper()
        
        super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: contentView)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            self.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        let theme = ThemeManager.currentTheme()
        return theme.statusBarColor
    }
    
}

struct MyCoreDataViewEnvironmentWrapper: View {
    private let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
//            TodayNavView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
            TestView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
        }
    }
}
```

TestView Code (Screen 1)

```
    struct TestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView2()) {
                
                Text("TAP TO EDIT")
                }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Screen 1", displayMode: .large)
    }
}
```

TestView2 Code (Screen 2)

```
struct TestView2: View {
    
    var body:some View {
        VStack{
            Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }.navigationBarTitle("Screen 2", displayMode: .large)
    }
}
```

EDIT: So I removed the tabBarController and made the Hosting VC the initial view controller and the problem goes away. It appears to me that the size of the grey area is the same as the tab bar.

EDIT 2: So After further testing it appears if I uncheck "Extend edges > Under Bottom Bars" on the Hosting VC in storyboard. The grey area appears in Screen 1 and doubles in size in Screen 2. But When I add a 3rd screen it doesn.t extend any more.

[image]

EDIT 3: I have setup a basic project from scratch and it seems that things work fine if the tab bar is set to translucent but it breaks if it isn't.

[image]

Comment: At this point, I think this needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will need some test data that Core Data would otherwise provide. The code we can run works fine, as you know.

Comment: To me it seems that the empty space at the bottom equals to the navigation bar height or the tab bar. Can you try to add a spacer in a Vstack and set color as a background of VStack?

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't do anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

When using UIHostingController SwiftUI wraps NavigationView into a regular UINavigationController, and for some reason the new UINavigationController believes that it should display a tab bar, resulting in two tab bars.

This can be solved by wrapping your UIHostingController in a UINavigationController like this:

```
UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIHostingController(rootView: CustomSwiftUIView()))
```

For a more in-depth answer view Xaxxus's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65692840/9986018)